# Design a structure for a File Uploader service (eg. google drive)

Tags: file, file-upload, dropbox, google-drive-realtime-api

Design a structure for a File Uploader service (eg. google drive) .It is a service where multiple person can upload data at same time and it also lists the top five uploaders (who uploaded maximum number of files).

This question was asked in an interview.Please help.Interviewer was more  interested in design interfaces ,classes and API needs to design..